# INSERT with several UPDATE statements

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, common-table-expression

What is the best way to solve the following issue with Postgresql?

For each row I INSERT into an article Table based on a SELECT from another table I want to UPDATE certain columns of the inserted articles.

This is my current solution:

```
-- temporarily alter table to avoid not null issues
ALTER TABLE article ALTER COLUMN fk_article_unit DROP NOT NULL;
(...)

--create article and return inserted pks, store these in a temporary table so they can be used for all following updates
WITH articles AS (
  insert into article
  (
    ...
  )
  select
    ...
  from other_table
  where some_condition
  RETURNING pk
)
SELECT pk INTO temporary temp_articles
FROM articles;

-- update various fk for all newly created articles
UPDATE article
SET fk_article_type =
  (SELECT pk
  FROM article_type
  WHERE unique_id = 'service')
WHERE pk in (select pk from temp_articles);

UPDATE article
SET fk_article_type =
  (SELECT min(pk)
  FROM vat_code)
WHERE fk_article_type is null;

(... several more updates)

--readd no null constraint
ALTER TABLE article ALTER COLUMN fk_article_type SET NOT NULL;
(...)
```

Comment: Does the INSERT leave `fk_article_type` null for all new rows? Are you asking how to incorporate the 2 following UPDATEs directly into the INSERT?

Comment: Hi Daniel. The INSERT might leave fk_article_type null for certain rows. I don't think incorporating the UPDATES will work in my complicated example (in this simplified one I guess it might be possible).

Comment: I guess I'm just wanting to know if my solution is a "good" solution or if I am doing something rather silly because there is a much easier/nicer/cleaner... way.

Comment: Toggling the NOT NULL constraint requires a strong lock on the table (excluding readers), and when putting it back, it will recheck the entire table. In high concurrency or big tables contexts, this is not ideal.

Comment: In my case that should not be a problem since the tables involved are generally not more than 100 rows and we only use this query during a migration. But I am still curious to know how this can be achieved without the toggling of the NOT NULL constraint. All in 1 query? So how do you handle the double update on the fk_article_type? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this can't be done with a single `insert` query. If the solution below doesn't apply please provide some additional information on your data model.

```
insert into article
(
  ...,
  fk_article_type
)
select
  ...,
  coalesce -- if first query is null, then the result of second will be used
  (
      ( -- 1st query
          select pk from article_type where unique_id= 'service'
      ),
      ( -- 2nd query
          select min(pk) from vat_code
      )
  )
from other_table
where some_condition
returning pk;
```

Comment: I can't try it out right now, but it looks awesome :). I made this way too complicated. I'll accept the answer once I can try it out :).